# Error while running pip install -r requirements.txt , Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-filters==2.4.0

Tags: python, django, command-line, pip, django-filter

Here is the command line output that I have got when I tried installing my requirements.txt inside a virtual env. It seems that there is some error with the django-filters version, but not sure what! I am so stuck with this, please help me. Thanks!

```
  Using cached asgiref-3.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting Babel==2.8.0
  Using cached Babel-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 MB)
Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0
  Using cached dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Django==3.0.6 in e:\..\..\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.0.6)
Collecting django-crispy-forms==1.9.0
  Using cached django_crispy_forms-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-filters==2.4.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-filters==2.4.0
```

Comment: can you provide more info on which platform you are installing this, also what version of python you have installed and are running this with

Comment: The package is called [`django-filter`](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/), not `django-filters`! `pip install django-filter==2.4.0` or `django-filter==2.4.0` in your `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

At this time which version is installed of Django-filters in your project ? If u don't have the version 2.4.0 then u have to uninstall the Django-filters and install django-filters 2.4.0 version

pip install django-filters==2.4.0